# How can I group data in R to make totals for each team?

Tags: r, statistics, data-manipulation

in R, I have a data set TABLE A and I would like to make it look like TABLE B. How can I manipulate it so that I can do so? Newbie here... Sorry if it's so blatantly simple

```
TABLE A 

 Team       Points
Raptors      101
Lakers       99
Raptors      104
Raptors      88
Celtics      89
Lakers       100
Celtics      112

TABLE B

 Team    Total_Points
Raptors      293
Lakers       199
Celtics      201
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `aggregate`

```
aggregate(cbind(Total_points = Points) ~ Team, df1, sum, 
        na.rm  = TRUE, na.action = NULL)
#     Team Total_points
#1 Celtics          201
#2  Lakers          199
#3 Raptors          293
```

---

Or with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    group_by(Team) %>%
    summarise(Total_Points = sum(Points, na.rm = TRUE))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#  Team    Total_Points
#  <chr>          <int>
#1 Celtics          201
#2 Lakers           199
#3 Raptors          293
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Team = c("Raptors", "Lakers", "Raptors", "Raptors", 
"Celtics", "Lakers", "Celtics"), Points = c(101L, 99L, 104L, 
88L, 89L, 100L, 112L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

Comment: Thank you so much @akrun! Would I have to get rid of rows with null values first?

Comment: @NickA use the `na.rm` in `sum`. updated the post

Comment: Wonderful! I thank you very much @akrun !